# DRF Throttling behaving extremely inconsistently?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication, throttling

I've been using an extremely basic user throttle rate with my DRF API and have been getting just... nonsensical results when I try to run benchmark tests.

For instance, when I set the throttle to 15/day my python benchmarker was able to make **29** (???) requests before actually being throttled.

Here are my base settings:

```
# Django Rest Framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = { 
...
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'user': '15/day'
    }
}
```

and here's my benchmarking program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import requests, time, datetime
from pprint import pprint
TOKEN = [redacted]
CSDB_NEXT_URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/siteroles?format=json"

response = requests.get(CSDB_NEXT_URL, headers={'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(TOKEN)})

startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(0, 52):
    data = requests.get(CSDB_NEXT_URL, headers={'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(TOKEN)}).json()
    if "Request was throttled" in str(data):
        break
endTime = datetime.datetime.now()
print(data, '\n', i, " requests made in ", endTime-startTime, " seconds.").
```

and which yielded

> [Running] /usr/bin/env python3
> "/Users/jgossett/Documents/gateway3/utils/benchmarks/test"
> {'detail':
> 'Request was throttled. Expected available in 86389 seconds.'}
> 29 requests made in  0:00:12.437853  seconds.
>
> [Done] exited with code=0 in 13.248 seconds

Now the number **29** here is especially troubling because it is larger than 15? Notably so? Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I found the cause of the inconsistency: my Django server is using the default LocMemCache whose multi-threaded cache system causes queries to be logged inconsistently [as was documented here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6730)